# MapView gone after publishing app in market.

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-mapview, google-play

I am using Google maps, my map view is working in debug mode and my last app uploaded is working fine, but when i export it with the release key and same keystore the map-view is not showing further, please help. I have tried with same keystore and new keystore.
i didn't found the solution.
**I have mentioned i used these keys i got keys. 
even new debug keystore, debug key from keytool and Api from google console**

Comment: Did you generate Map API key for your for app keystore file? not for debug.keystore

Comment: You have to obtain your release.key's hash code, i wrote below you can look at that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Command Promt
Goto your SDK location (for ex, c:\android-sdk\tools)

I:\keypath\my-release-key.keystore  = it is your release key location which you use to sign your app

type below and press enter
keytool -v -list -keystore I:\Android\1_RELEASED_APP\0-key\my-release-key.keystore

it asks for key password type it and click enter,

then it generates and hash code

copy that code  and

goto [there](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup)

Generate your key with this hash code, and use it(MD5) your application which you will publish.

[image]

Comment: is this the same keytool which i am using from JDK folder ?

Comment: Yes same keytool. (to use this without giving its path, you must add JDK/bin pat to environment variables or use keytool "JDK path\keytool" )

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the API key for the signing certificate and replace it.

[Obtain map key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)

Comment: i have mentioned that i used that key .. it was working for my first release but not now .. even i have generated new one

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between the debug.keystore and release keystore. Your bold lines in your question state you generated new Debug Keys, which you should not do. Each time you update your app on the market, you should sign it with the same key as before; not generating new keys each time.

You need to get a signed API Key; which can be generated by using the same key you are signing your application with.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey has some more info on it.

If you generate a new keystore key, you also need to generate a new Google Maps API Key as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two things to look for:

1> Your are using the same keystore to sign your application which you used to obtain google map keys.
2> You are signing your application from the same machine your signed earlier.

There should not be any problem if you have done these things.